# Why might a thick wire be bad?

Tags: wire

[This](https://robu.in/product/tp4056-1a-lipo-battery-charging-board-micro-usb-with-current-protection/) Battery Charger has the following line in its notes:

3. The connection wire should not be too thick.

Why might that be? Aren't thicker wires supposed to be better? What issue might a thick wire cause?

Comment: *"The connection wire should not be too thick* is meaningless. Given also that the note was from a website page and not a product data sheet makes it more meaningless. Added to this is the serious problem of the device not appearing to have a product data sheet. This makes your question "unclear" and quite possibly inappropriate for this site.

Comment: I was just wondering if a thick wire might lead to any issues and hence phrased the question as such. But if that is "unclear" or "too broad", I understand that the question must be closed.

Answer (score 1):

From your link, a battery wire too thick would not go through the holes in the PCB, forcing the user to make unwise choices, like soldering on one side only or trying to reduce the wire's gauge manually.

Comment: Even when the wire fits through the hole, it still can be soldered on one side only, so I wonder that argument holds

Comment: @Huisman I Believe it does, having the wire pass through the hole does not guarantee a good soldering job, but soldering from one side only does.